# Retag request: [appwidget] to [android-appwidget]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I've been doing research on Android AppWidgets lately, and I notice the tagging here is pretty inconsistent.

Currently there are two tags which I see used repeatedly for question about android appwidgets:

- [appwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appwidget) - "*Appwidget is a disambiguation of the word "widget", which can either mean: (1) a small application (for example a clock), embedded in an host (your desktop) - this is an appwidget. (2) a gui element (a button, text field or dropdown).*"
- [android-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-widget) - "*UI elements to use on an Android Application screen.*"

[appwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appwidget) is ambiguous and seems like a generic tag, so I think instead of using that many users are choosing to tag their AppWidget questions with [android-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-widget), which is an incorrect usage of that tag.

There are 349 questions tagged [appwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appwidget), and it appears that every single one of them is either tagged android (334 of them), or about android and not tagged as such (15 of them).

I think it would be better if this was clearly made an android tag [android-appwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appwidget), such that people would tag their appwidget questions as such instead of choosing [android-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-widget), which seems more on-topic but is incorrect.

Comment: I agree that we should synonym [appwidget] -> [android-appwidget]. I have re-tagged the last few questions which were not about android.