# Fixing the un-prefixed Android tags

Tags: discussion, tags

From the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) wiki:

> When tagging additional tags to questions, please use the
>   Android-specific tags such as [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) and [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity), not
>   [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) and [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity).

However, this is very frequently overlooked by new (and no-so-new) users, resulting in an endless supply of tags that are very Android-specific but not Android-prefixed. I could spend the next few days retagging [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) questions with [android-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-listview) and I probably wouldn't make a measurable dent, but that's not why I'm here right now.

When the **android-specific tag exists**, such as in the case of [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), the solution is obvious. Simply retag the question as [android-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-listview) and go on with your day. *(Note: this category is also a problem, but a different discussion).*

However, when the **tag doesn't exist**, what is the proper action? [layerdrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layerdrawable) is easy to fix because there are only 18 questions. I could simply create the new tag and retag all of the old questions. However, some such as [drawerlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawerlayout) have quite a few more questions, and would be a bit more work to deal with.

Is the proper action in this case to create the new tag, then create a question here requesting that a mod merge the two tags, such as 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132411/merge-mapview-into-android-mapview?

Another option I have seen some users take is to create the new tag and mark the old one as a synonym, such as with [arrayadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrayadapter) and [android-arrayadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-arrayadapter). My only qualm with this option is that it could create problems or confusion if any other language/platform/company decides to use the word marked as a synonym in the future.

<sub>A history of past similar threads: [Propose to merge SO tags 'android-intent' and 'intent'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252416/propose-to-merge-so-tags-android-intent-and-intent), [Merge tags [contentprovider] and [android-contentprovider] and [content-provider]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252412/merge-tags-contentprovider-and-android-contentprovider-and-content-provider), [Merge tags [contentprovider] and [android-contentprovider] and [content-provider]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252412/merge-tags-contentprovider-and-android-contentprovider-and-content-provider), [Merge tags [cursorloader] and [android-cursorloader]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252414/merge-tags-cursorloader-and-android-cursorloader), [Retag request: [appwidget] to [android-appwidget]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252210/retag-request-appwidget-to-android-appwidget), [Synonym request - [android-edittext] -> [edittext]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252395/synonym-request-android-edittext-edittext)</sub>

Comment: Has `intent` been merged, or is it just a synonym?

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm not sure how to tell whether a tag has become a synonym or merged, or what the difference is (if there is any).

Comment: Find it on [the synonyms page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) - if there's a number (`× nnnn`) listed after the synonym, they haven't been merged yet.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359792/synonym-of-relativelayout

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359078/make-connectivitymanager-a-synonym-of-android-connectivitymanager

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359324/make-vectordrawable-a-synonym-of-android-vectordrawable

Comment: Related, completed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295916/lets-recycle-recyclerview

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359090/merge-architecture-components-into-android-architecture-components

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314896/merging-of-android-navigation-drawer-and-navigation-drawer

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291894/merge-synonymize-proposal-uiautomator-android-uiautomator

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318769/merge-broadcastreceiver-and-android-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256102/merge-synonym-toast-and-android-toast

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300827/merge-alertdialog-and-android-alertdialog

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280524/should-the-tags-videoview-and-android-videoview-be-merged

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318170/merge-request-for-2-tags-textview-and-android-textview

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360849/merge-tags-fragmentmanager-and-android-fragmentmanager

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311370/tag-synonyms-android-avd-and-avd

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283800/split-android-appcompat-out-to-android-appcompat

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350722/merge-tags-android-sharedpreferences-and-sharedpreferences

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385160/can-we-make-cardview-a-synonym-of-android-cardview

Comment: Now, @VadimKotov, can you do a quick run through your comments and check the status? thanks

Comment: @BhargavRao should I delete it if it is completed or what?

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually *have* to create the new tag first if you're gonna ask a moderator to rename - they can merge an existing tag into a non-existent tag, creating and synonymizing them in the process. This also guarantees the existing tag wiki is preserved.

In fact, unless you plan to retag enough of them to allow you to suggest a synonym on your own, there's no point - it's just going to cause confusion.

If you can handle the entire process yourself (retagging all questions to have the new tag) then you might want to open up a meta discussion just to let folks know what you're doing, but for *very* obscure tags even this isn't strictly necessary.