# Synonym request - [android-edittext] -> [edittext]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

These tags seem to be referring to the same thing, as only [73 questions tagged [edittext] don't have the [android] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext+-android) (while most seem to refer to it).

I'm not sure which way this should go, but the [edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext) (x2,279) & [android-edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-edittext) (x1,026) are being used for the same purpose.

Personally, I think [android-edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-edittext) should burn, as [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) & [edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext) convey exactly the same information as the longer tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The prevailing opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) on these tags appears to be to use the "android-" prefix. Therefore, I've merged and synonymized [edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext) with [android-edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-edittext).

Comment: Thanks for picking up this tumbleweed, Shog!

Comment: Thank the folks who flagged / closed this and all the related ones on MSE