# Merge tags [contentprovider] and [android-contentprovider] and [content-provider]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I propose we merge these three tags together. Almost all of the tags that are tagged [contentprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contentprovider) and [content-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-provider) are also under the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, and those that are not are clearly Android-related questions.

---

## Before:

[contentprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contentprovider) **x 507**

[android-contentprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contentprovider) **x 181**

[content-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-provider) **x 20**

## After:

[android-contentprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contentprovider) **x 708**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've moved everything into the [android-contentprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contentprovider) tag.  The tag wiki will have to be rebuilt (it was only a blurb to begin with).

I've not created synonyms though.  [content-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-provider) (or it's variants) are *way* too general purpose to be associated with a specific class name for Android.

Comment: I actually thought about whether or not SO would want to enforce `content-provider` mapping to `android-contentprovider` and I figured it would be too strict as well. I guess I will just have to clean up after all of the other Android people who tag their questions under `content-provider` :P. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexLockwood The way I've done it, it should have the same rep requirements for creating new tags, so `content-provider` shouldn't be created except by people with enough rep.  Of course, that won't stop them, but hopefully auto-complete will help guide the way.