# Merge tags [cursorloader] and [android-cursorloader]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I propose we merge these two tags together.

All 41 of the questions tagged under [cursorloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursorloader) are also tagged under the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.

---

## Before:

[cursorloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursorloader) **x 41**

[android-cursorloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cursorloader) **x 16**

## After:

[android-cursorloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cursorloader) **x 57**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Completed (posting this wiki answer to get the question off the unanswered page, please upvote).