# Propose to merge SO tags 'android-intent' and 'intent'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Currently on stackoverflow.com, there are 275 questions tagged [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent), and 910 questions tagged [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent).  Of the 'intent' tagged questions, only one is not about Android intents, and it is legitimately about another technology of the same name.

[Fortran intent(inout) versus omitting intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880537/fortran-intentinout-vs-no-intent)

Since the term 'android-intent' is arguably less ambiguous than 'intent', even though more than 99% of questions tagged 'intent' are about Android intents, and since more than one technology shares this name, I propose retagging the 909 Android 'intent' questions as 'android-intent'.

If someone with permission to do this disagrees, then please at least change 'android-intent' tags to 'intent'.

Comment: I have retagged the FORTRAN one to remove the [tag:intent] as there are only a handful of us folks left who need to care and the FORTRAN tag is enough.

Comment: So essentially you want [tag:android-intent] to be a tag synonym of [tag:intent]?

Comment: Yes, or the other way around.

Answer (score 9):

I think it would probably be better to make [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) be a synonym for [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent), as the latter is less ambiguous to the reader, there's no difference as far as the search engines are concerned, and that makes it possible for [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) to be used for something else in the future without a major retagging exercise.

Oh, and write a good tag wiki (or at least an excerpt) once the merge is done, please! Help to educate those of us (like me!) who know nothing about the technology being identified…

Comment: FWIW, I usually prefer to merge to the most common tag on the grounds that that's “proved itself most strongly in the market”, but in this case going to the least ambiguous tag is better IMO.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't you just tag those questions with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent)?

Comment: At the time of my original post above, all 'intent' tagged posts were already also tagged 'android' (except the one FORTRAN post).  The issue is overlap with the 'android-intent' tag.

Comment: @Programmer Bruce: Doesn't that just reaffirm the fact that android and intent should be separate tags? Why the need to duplicate 'android'? Similarly it is not .net-linq but just linq.

Comment: The point is to merge 'android-intent' with 'intent'.

Comment: That isn't that clear. :) Your first point is _"I propose retagging the 909 Android 'intent' questions as 'android-intent'."_. Only your second is: _"If someone with permission to do this disagrees, then please at least change 'android-intent' tags to 'intent'."_. But in the first case, yes I agree. ;p