# Merge/Synonym [toast] and [android-toast]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I was reviewing some posts tonight when I noticed that the tags [toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toast) and [android-toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-toast). I initially thought that toast notifications only referred to the android variant but while looking at some of the questions I see it can also relate to windows phone. If that is the case then should there be a [android-toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-toast) and a [windows-toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-toast) tag? Or would it be better to have [toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toast) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)?

I would make the synonym request myself however i'm just shy of the 2500 rep needed to do it. Should somebody do this?

Comment: I think [toast] shouldn't exist at all. Retag it.

Comment: Toasts are actually somewhat ubiquitous. I'm not sure a synonym would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree with boltclock. It's about the concept of a toast notification, if you want an android toast look for questions tagged both android and toast.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum so should I attempt to retag all questions in [android-toast] to [android] and [toast] and then make another post here for a burminate request?

Comment: @secretformula that's a bit the same issue as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba), where the final answer was you should include all relevant tags ([toast], [android-toast] and [android] if you wanted to post a question about android toasts). No burninate was done there, so I think it's not appropriate here either.