# Add VB syntax highlighting for [*-vba] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

We have VB syntax highlighting, and it's already used for [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). However, [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba), [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba), [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) and [powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba) do not have syntax highlighting.

I'd like syntax highlighting to be added for these tags.

There's an argument to be made that some questions are also tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), and thus already have syntax highlighting, but in the case of [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba), that's only about 50% (9,359 questions, of which 4,654 are also tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba))

If someone is willing to add them to smaller tags too (these are more often used in conjunction with the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag, and less alone), there are even more:

[visio-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visio-vba), [microsoft-project-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-vba) and [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac) are smaller tags that use the VBA language and could benefit from syntax highlighting.

Comment: It will get the `lang-vb` prettifier.  That is what you intend, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the right one!

Comment: Is there a reason that this was never implemented?

Comment: Voting to close as no repro because [the `[*-vba]` tags have now mostly been removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393153/status-of-removing-the-excel-vba-and-similar-vba-tags), with only one left and that one being scheduled for removal (can't delete because of the answer).

Answer (score -5):

[`x-vba` tags are not recommended for continued use](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba).

The proposed feature would work against that goal, perpetuating the dichotomy that currently exists.

Comment: I highly doubt the presence or absence of syntax highlighting has a major impact in the number of questions posted. Taryn shared _Based on the number of people who would be impacted by removing excel-vba, it's not likely we'd remove the tag._. This is not an answer to my question imo, and my request stands.

Comment: Correction: _you_ do not recommend those tags for continued use. The answers to that meta question of yours conclude that reaching your goal is not practical. Rejecting a feature request for the sake of chasing that goal anyway, is like cutting off your nose to spite your face (i.e. ultimately counter-productive).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The answer never says that "reaching your goal is not practical". It confirms the dichotomy as a valid concern and only says that the specific proposition at the specific point in time is not practical.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: If there's a distinction between "proposition" and "goal" in this context I'm not seeing it. Feel free to propose something that can actually be accomplished. Otherwise, what you have suggested is not in any way being actioned, and so leaning on it to make decisions about other things on the network is silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Easy. The goal is to get rid of the dichotomy (see the linked question why). That proposed solution was rejected? Fine. I'll keep looking for other opportunities to make a stab at this problem. This is one.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Heh, touché. I still think it's dishonest to imply here that the goal is a community consensus, though.