# Access in programming is more than just VBA. Leave the access-vba tag alone

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

[ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) is a mixed bag of topics: you have a database file, a database viewer that can read from any database provided it knows how to, forms, reports, etc.

There are way more disparate programming problems that involve MS Access than VBA. You can have C# questions, you can have python questions, some database clients can read mdb files and accdb (as I'm sure you would find old libraries too). Merging [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) questions into access offer no alternative to have pure VBA questions other than having custom search for all of them.

That would be disastrous for people like me that want to reach only those users instead of all ms-access users. Furthermore, Excel woes don't affect ms-access questions, where Excel questions were too popular (for some reason) and there wasn't an agreement of how correctly tag these questions. Sadly, these questions now have tags that weren't there added in the last 2 days, so I can't show evidence to this (SEDE was updated also).

These tags don't cause disturbance. The [Excel thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) was already a mess, don't involve other tags in it.

Comment: This is not clear. What are you advocating or against?

Comment: @philipxy there's a "plan" of merging all app-vba questions into their plain app tag. That is bonkers since it would mix 100% programming questions with all the "is this even programming" questions. I propose a counter plan on this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399320/disambiguate-all-ms-access-questions

Comment: I know what the question is about generally but your post is not clear, also it should be self-contained, also please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy "Leave access-vba alone!" is this post summed up. The last sentence attest to that.

Answer (score 12):

This fight has been [fought](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893).

Yes, there are many ways to program against Microsoft Access. That goes for Excel too. And many of these questions are not interesting for users who's primary expertise is in VBA.

That's exactly why in the initial planning, the removal of the excel-vba tag was delayed to wait for custom filters. Currently, you can filter questions to only get questions tagged both ms-access and vba. Or, specifically not vba.

We can repeat arguments already had in that linked discussion, but the intent behind that was: *"speak now, or forever hold your peace"*. Well, many words have been spoken. Multiple times. A consensus was reached, and while we may not all agree with it, I will honor it.

All other *-vba tags have already been removed, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177/7296893). Access-vba has only been spared due to the vast amount of questions using it as a tag that don't have the ms-access tag.

Currently, I'm working on mitigating that last point. I will be adding the ms-access tag to all questions tagged access-vba, by using a bot to edit them. I won't remove the access-vba tag, so I won't interfere with this discussion. I will spread out edits throughout the day, keeping the (quite low) quotum in mind, to try to reduce the homepage from overflowing. Due to some test runs I'm out for today, but will continue in approximately 12 hours, if there are no strong objections.

It would be more optimal to have a CM perform these edits, in a similar way that Shog9 added the excel tag for the excel-vba questions, but as I understand it that's not currently feasible.

Comment: That fight hasn't been fought! That's a falacy. The (flawed) arguments that were used in the excel tag aren't applicable at all in the case of access. Nobody is complaining about access questions. You aren't! Leave those tags alone that they are doing fine.

Comment: BTW, if the "community" really thinks that they can screw over users just because they can, I don't want anything to do with said community.

Comment: @Braiam I get that you feel passionate about these tags but I personally think it isn't a strong case if you use phrases like "screw over users". That can hardly turn into debate about facts, nor something anyone can formulate a reasonable response to without making it about users.

Comment: @rene because it has to be said. This kind of actions screw over users. Users that answers my questions. Users that look for answers.

Comment: @Braiam maybe we need to do a show of hands: *Please raise your hand if you were screwed over!* Okay, that is one. *Now please raise your hand if you were unscrewed?* ...

Comment: Is the goal to remove access-vba? I see braX has been systematically removing these tags all year. I just rolled back two edits that were definitely access-vba questions. But now I'm wondering if I missed something? You mention that your bot was not going to do this very thing.

Comment: @dbmitch The goal of my bot was to add the [tag:ms-access] tag to all questions tagged [tag:access-vba], so that if a mod wanted to, they could remove [tag:access-vba] by merging it with [tag:vba]. That's done, so a mod can now do this easily without having to worry about questions lacking the info that they're about both Access and VBA. I'm unsure what the goal of the edits by braX is.

Comment: @rene if people can't look past and see the argument by what it is, is because I desired to do so: the oposing argument doesn't make sense on its merits. If mine is hurt just because it doesn't follow form is because I decided to do so. I don't want that my argument wins because it sounds good, but because it is right. People isn't looking past flowery language and identifying a BS argument by what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The `access-vba` tag is no more.

I merged it into [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) after [Erik A.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a) ran a script to add [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) to all posts tagged with `access-vba` but missing that crucial tag. This means that all posts that were previously tagged `access-vba` are now tagged [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access), in line with the tag use for the other VBA host applications.

Comment: Just for info: somebody seems to be trying to revive the [access-vba] tag. There's a comment, an edit and a rollback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56612992/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole: looks like it was resolved, the tag is still gone.