# Disambiguate all ms-access questions

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-disambiguation

Microsoft access is a mixed bag of topics, which most have tags for them, but MS access (the program without database capabilities) isn't software development without these topics.

So I propose moving all ms-access questions to their respective and more specific tags:

- Questions about forms: [ms-access-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access-forms)
- Questions about VBA using Access: [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba)
- Questions about ODBC: [odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odbc)
- Questions about the file formats: [mdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdb) and [accdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accdb)
- Questions about libraries that consume the files or interface using ocdb, use the library/framework and the file or ocdb driver tag.

> Wait, doesn't that mean that the ms-access tag would disappear?

Yes. That's the objective. A pure Access question isn't on topic. If you strip access of forms and vba, programmers wouldn't touch it with a 10 foot pole (given that the file format is proprietary and finikly at that). I may be missing another type of question, but that can be created easily for those questions.

There's only one problem with the plan above and is that the file formats are synonymized with ms-access tag, so that should be removed.

Comment: Note, I've written this in haste and without proper planning since it is planned to do the same barbarity that happened with excel-vba. This is the counterplan to that in the way that it actually make sense and what I was expecting to write as solution to the excel tag debacle but sadly couldn't since I don't know much about excel.

Comment: Also, I kinda forgot about it.

Comment: excel-vba could have some questions cleaned up, and then have the entire tag split with fancy mod and/or staff tools. This would require manually editing 48000 questions with context in mind. The removal of excel-vba is like the removal of a NAA answer in comparison

Comment: @Zoe access is easier. Get all the questions with ms-access + vba to have the access-vba. Remove ms-access. Only ~3k questions would need manual intervention as they only have ms-access tag https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1209144/find-questions-with-one-and-only-one-tag?tag=ms-access I cannot comment on how could have happened with ms-excel.

Comment: @Zoe No tools exist anymore, aside from a moderator's ability to create synonyms and/or merge one tag into another. The tools that used to be available were built and operated by Shog9, who is no longer employed by Stack Exchange. The employees who still work there either don't know how to use the tools, don't have the required privileges, and/or are restricted by policy from operating scripts on their computers with the required level of privileges. This is why Martijn's only option for [[tag:excel-vba]] was a manual cleanup and retag, and will be the only option in the future, too.

Comment: @Zoe: note that `excel-vba` no longer exists, I edited some ~1000 posts to ensure that they all had [tag:vba] listed too, then merged `excel-vba` into [tag:excel]. See [Status of removing the Excel-vba (and similar -vba) tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177). Thanks to Erik A.'s efforts with updating tags on `access-vba` posts we managed to do the same for that tag now.

Answer (score 9):

**Summary:** I disagree; disambiguation should be provided by flexible combinations of tags, not single monolithic tags.

I strongly disagree with this proposal. There's a reason why the tag system allows up to 5 tags. It is neither necessary nor desirable to have single, monolithic tags that describe the entire content of the question. A question can be adequately tagged by [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and/or [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms).

A further justification for this is that VBA experts can answer pretty much any question about Office VBA, regardless of whether it's in the context of [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) or [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) (or, indeed, any other Office suite product that uses VBA). Since the purpose of the tagging system is to categorize questions and ultimately allow people to find them, pigeonholing questions about VBA into [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) just because they happen to be in the context of Microsoft Access would be a major step backwards.

The same goes for questions about Forms.

Your implicit interpretation of the tag system would result in an infinite regress, where we have to tag questions [ms-access-vba-programming-with-forms-using-jet-via-odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access-vba-programming-with-forms-using-jet-via-odbc). Once you allow [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) + [odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odbc), you have a situation no different than what is currently the accepted practice, namely: [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) + [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) + [odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odbc) + [jet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jet). Aside from simplicity and convention, the latter has a clear advantage in being extensively recombinable during search.

You've also trotted out the same tired logic that I am on record for having disagreed with countless times, namely that having a tag named [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) might imply that general, non-programming questions about Access are on-topic here. Of course that is not true, any more than having the tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) implies that questions about large, non-venomous snakes are on-topic here, or having the tag [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) implies that questions about brewing coffee are on-topic here. All of our tag names are interpreted in terms of the site's topical focus, which, in the case of Stack Overflow, is programming. Non-programming questions about Access aren't allowed, and the tagging system doesn't need to call that out each time, as it just adds pointless noise.

Comment: @ErikA I'm afraid you may have OCDB... ;-)

Comment: Constructing sentences as tags was what we don't want. Tag combination breaks the site tools for askers and answerers: if you know only about a subset of the topic (ie. access-vba), it would give you privileges on topics you may know nothing about (ie. access-forms), they are also difficult to follow if you are interested in one kind of questions.

Comment: "Once you allow access-vba + odbc, you have a situation no different than what is currently the accepted practice, namely: ms-access + vba + forms + odbc + jet." Why two tags is no different than 5 tags? Two tags that describe everything you need to know about the topic is easier to manage. Tags are supposed to be "specific, well-defined categories", forms isn't that. Your counterargument is that by allowing focused tags you are allowing unfocused ones is non-sequitur.