# Activate [deno] syntax highlighting without having to tag [javascript] or [typescript]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[deno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deno) is a secure runtime for JavaScript and TypeScript, however unlike nodejs it doesn't *yet* have syntax highlighting.

Would it be possible to activate syntax highlighting for Deno without having to tag the question with [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) ?

Comment: since it is a js runtime, would the tag javascript not be apropriate for it?

Comment: @clockw0rk I had similar thoughts but nodejs doesn't require js tag to have syntax highlighting. Either we add it for both or remove it for both.

Comment: Afaik we have many libraries/runtimes linked to specific languages, but that don't have syntax highlighting for that language. The deno tag seems to have few questions, even fewer without a javascript or typescript tag. Don't see why this specific one needs syntax highlighting

Comment: @ErikA So we wait until it's a bigger problem, then fix it? You've never lived in a basement apartment in a flood zone, have you. :) It would take a mod a few seconds to update the spot in the tag info page where it's set.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well, my reference point is [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364023/7296893) (posted before it got announced the *-vba tags would get removed), which affected ~5.000 questions and got ignored. Combine that with hundreds of similar tags existing, and I think that posting questions like these is not a good idea, and we should focus on a systematic fix for the issue instead, plus just tagging questions with the language used.