# Tag vigilantism vs. common courtesy

Tags: discussion, tags

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760504/mailitem-move-vs-outlook-manual-move-within-exchange-mailbox) some months ago on an Outlook VBA topic, duly tagged as [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba). Within a minute, another user [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59760504/revisions) the question and removed the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag with no comment or explanation (leaving the other [outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tags in place). A few days later I noticed the edit, and rolled it back to restore the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag, which happens to be the single best fitting tag among the three. Then a month later the same user edited the question again, and removed the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag the second time. I only noticed that last week, and once again I put the tag back, also leaving a comment to ask "why". The next day the user removed the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag for the third time, again without any comment or explanation. At that point I raised a moderator flag, though it doesn't look like any action was taken since.

I consider such edits to be "question vandalism", and not respecting OP's choice of tags plain rude. As long as the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag is in good standing, and as long as it clearly is the most appropriate tag for the question, I expect it to be left in place, though I don't have the means to enforce that as an end user.

P.S. A search in the meta archives found several discussions about the perceived duplication of the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)/[outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tags vs. the separate [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)/[outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). There does not appear to exist a consensus on the matter, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356080).

However, it looks like certain users took upon themselves to impose their preference and systematically "cleanse" the combination tags. The [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) tag, for example, had 3,100 questions in [Nov '19](https://web.archive.org/web/20191105065151/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba), while it is down to 2,800 today, with an year-long gap due to systematic deletions of the tag from previously posted questions.

Comment: You linked to my answer, claiming that it justifies your use of an [[tag:outlook-vba]] tag. It does not. The consensus is clear, for reasons clearly explained in that answer. You should be using separate tags. Either way, calling this "vandalism" or "vigilantism" is just an absurd exaggeration. Users are encouraged to retag questions when they have been mistagged. They're *not supposed* to provide any sort of explanation. There is absolutely nothing about retagging questions that violates "common courtesy". In fact, it is courteous to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray 1) If you read my question, the tag is entirely "justified". If you feel my question is off-topic for that tag then I'd more than happy to defend that point, but that's another matter entirely. Anyway, I did not link your post to "justify" my choice of tags. I linked it as an example of "*there does not appear to exist a consensus*" and, indeed, the first half of your answer (before "*all of that to say ..*) summarizes it quite well.

Comment: @CodyGray 2) So moderator's advice is to either live with the abusive edits, or maybe keep restoring the deleted tags in a pointless never-ending game. That's quite disappointing, but thank you for your input anyway.

Comment: You're missing the point. I don't need to read your question about Outlook VBA to determine whether the [[tag:outlook-vba]] tag is justified. The tag is *never* justified, *regardless* of the question, since separate tags should be used instead: [[tag:outlook]] and [[tag:vba]]. I said elsewhere that a massive retagging of all *old* questions is not a good idea for a variety of reasons, but I don't have any issue with users retagging new, incoming questions. In fact, that's what they should do. **They're not abusive edits**; someone is helping you to fix up the tags on your question.

Comment: @CodyGray I think you are missing my point as well. The site presents `outlook-vba` as a legitimate tag. Now, *after* I used the tag in good faith for precisely its intended purpose, you are saying that it should *never* be used. If that's the case then, sorry, but it would moderators' job to make that crystal clear upfront, and carry out whatever remediation *they* deem necessary. Leaving it to random users to do it unchecked and with impunity does make it look a lot like bullying.

Comment: This site is moderated by the community. Regular community members ("random users") handle the retagging, not diamond moderators. No one is accusing you of using the tag in bad faith. The problem only came after you refused to allow your question to be edited, which *is* the remediation.

Comment: @CodyGray I could be wrong here, but it seems to me that dxiv is arguing at this point for some sort of note on the original tag that it shouldn't be used for future questions.

Comment: @CodyGray Is `outlook-vba` the only such "poison tag", and how is one supposed to know? If it is, indeed, then it should be made read-only (if technically possible), and/or adorned with a big official warning. Barring that, arbitrary removal of the tag from qualifying questions is not any remediation, at least it surely doesn't look like one to an unsuspecting user.

Comment: Neither of those things are possible. The former not at all; the latter would require developer support and can't be done by moderators alone. It is standard practice here for new questions to get retagged in accordance with our tagging system. I don't really see the problem. You seem to be trying to make everything official, but the tagging system on Stack Overflow is anything *but* official. It's maintained by the community. Their mechanism for "enforcement" is making edits to questions that retag them. The tagging system is changed in precisely the same way: by retagging edits.

Comment: @CodyGray So, on the assumption that I am as much a member of the community as any other random user, my civic duty is to correct tags to what I consider to be the *right* ones, regardless of OP's expressed intent, or even common courtesy. Got it ;-) Over and out.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm having trouble reconciling your *[outlook-vba] is never justified* here with the ultimate paragraph of your answer there, where you seem to advocate its use with a "use all three"(paraphrase). Also the tag help tooltip says exactly what the tag is for, it contains no advisory not to use it/to use outlook+vba and the question does appear to be asking in line with what the tooltip says

Comment: @dxiv forgetting the tag for a moment, your question should contain the code you have written and are complaining to be defective

Comment: @CodyGray *"You should be using separate tags"* - Oh that's funny, I thought the concensus was don't burninate the old tags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370101. And even from Shog's originial question: *"excel-vba are* ***also*** *tagged excel and vba"*. People always go on about this "concensus" that was reached on the vba tags... but there never was one

Comment: @Nick Then someone needs to go fix the usage guidance for [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) which currently says not to use it.

Comment: @CaiusJard First off, thank you for actually *reading* the question. About the (missing) "*code*", quoting from SO's [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "*Not all questions benefit from including code.*". My question is about the behavior on an API in a given configuration, not tied to any particular code context. I'd be happy to followup on further comments about any of that under the original question.

Comment: @BSMP so there's a usage guidance on excel-vba saying not I use it but not one on outlook-vba? (I've only looked at the outlook one)

Comment: @dxiv my point was that making a question like "I've used some code like this one here (insert link liable to rot) and get some undesirable behavior x; why is that?" and not including the code means it's harder for someone to know exactly what you're doing or reproduce your issue exactly. Maybe if you posted the code someone would just look and say "oh, you've forgotten to supply a value for the moveOriginalToDeletedItems parameter which defaults to true" or whatever - without your exact code that can't be said. Posting the code allows the reader to decide if it's useful to them..

Comment: @CaiusJard There are cases where an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is essential, indeed. But in my question [MailItem.Move](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) has no other/hidden arguments, and the whole question is about a particular behavior of `objItem.Move objDestFolder` regardless of context. The post included a link to sample/boilerplate code, though that is immaterial to the question itself.

Comment: @CaiusJard Correct.

Answer (score 17):

> I consider such edits to be "question vandalism", and not respecting OP's choice of tags plain rude.

There a couple of misconceptions here.

Respecting the author choices is not paramount in many ways in how the site operates. The original intent is to be preserved as long as it complies with the site rules, but barring that the original author choices take a back-seat to rules and community consensus.

E.g. adding salutations may be part of the author choices, but they are removed as a matter of fact. And like that, countless examples.

Performing tag-edits to make questions follow more closely site's consensus is certainly **not vandalism**. Is what's expected to happen. We are all volunteers here, and editing work is among the most important kinds of work to be done.

I can't comment much on the tag situation. It appears the consensus regarding [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook) and [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) mostly leans towards using separate tags. Personally, if I were interested in the technologies involved at all, I think I would be initially inclined to prefer the [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) style, although I am not unswayed by Cody's arguments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba/356080#356080).

And in the end if it were a playground I played at, I'd go with the flow, not against it. Tends to be more productive in a community-like site like this.

**If you want to change consensus, the appropriate way it to engage meta with arguments and data**. It's not easy, and I'm not to say if it's worth your time, but it's not impossible.

Engaging in rollback wars is not productive, or deliberately disregard consensus either (since invites the former). The likely outcome would be for a mod to intervene (likely following the existing consensus; and even locking the post for further edits if the edit war continues).

Regarding the "common courtesy" angle: the only thing I find less than great in those edits is that the user performing them could, if not on the first edit then any of the following, have added some additional comment on why they were performing the edits at all, to help the question author understand that was not done simply out of whim.

If not altogether rude, I find the continued unexplained edits to be not-constructive, even if the edits themselves were not wrong, and that that attitude didn't create productive atmosphere.

Even if they were right, engaging in edit-wars is not the way to go.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for a thoughtful answer. However, I don't quite see the "consensus" here (beyond one vocal mod). Closest I found on a similar topic is Shag9's *attempt* to build/gauge the consensus on the `excel-vba` tag [a couple of years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/). It doesn't look like a consensus emerged even there - the top voted answer says keep the tag, the second one maybe drop it but we need more opinions, and so on. Without the presumption of a consensus *against* `outlook-vba` the advice to (essentially) just "live with it" rings rather hollow.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There is no "*automatic*" re-tagging in this case, and I am not sure what you mean by "*semi-automatic*". If that's about users who indiscriminately re-tag questions without reading them, and without justifying their choice to re-tag even when directly interpellated then, yes, it appears to be happening and that's precisely what my question here is about. There *is* an automatic script SO runs daily to catch "serial downvoting". I wonder why there isn't one for "serial re-tagging".

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would welcome your thoughts on "serial re-tagging".