# Demise of a tag

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation, burninate-system, rules

- Is it expected that one (or a minority of) determined user(s) be able to single-handedly purge/delete a tag, without discussion or dueness?
- If not, are there - or should there be - any safeguards in place to prevent that from happening?

[image: Graph showing an increase from 0 in May 2009 to over 3,000 in February of 2020 then a sharp plummet back to 0 by July 2020.]

A decade old tag was terminated yesterday. It was a niche but otherwise healthy tag, with steady followers and some high quality participation. A few months ago, some users started systematically removing the tag from old questions. That was the turning point in the graph above, though the tag still had close to 3,000 questions as of last month. Then the count suddenly dropped to 0 and the tag was subsequently deleted, all in less than 3 weeks.

This can be mainly attributed to one user, who went on a tag-removal spree to the tune of hundreds a day. The user had no presence in the respective tag or the related tags that "inherited" the questions, but happens to be a high-rep diamond mod. When asked, he stated that "*The tag is being removed site-wide*" then ignored the following question "*How/why was decided that 'the tag is being removed site-wide'?*" and went on with the cleansing.

I could find no prior discussion or announcement on meta about the removal of this particular tag, and nothing was posted under [burninate-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) or [retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request) either. Which goes back to the question at the top of my post.

<sub>P.S. *The names of the tag and user(s) are irrelevant, which is why I Ieft them out. My question is not about a specific tag or anyone in particular, but rather about praxes in general. So, please do not bring those names into discussion. Thank you.*</sub>

Comment: Yes, there is an expectation that tag removal be discussed on Meta. However, removal of product-specific variants of the VBA tags has been discussed *multiple* times on Meta. This one started being discussed circa 2013. I think that's long enough. Additionally, the moderator who removed the tag was primarily *undoing* a mass *addition* of the tag by another user, which was also done without discussion.

Comment: @CodyGray 1) I did not find this tag being discussed. If you are implying that it was simply "*guilty by association*" then that's rather arbitrary, rash judgement. 2) I do not see any "*mass addition*" in the posted curve, based on wayback snapshots. 3) It now sounds like you want to walk back what you previously said: "*Regular community members ("random users") handle the retagging, not diamond moderators.*".

Comment: @CodyGray This tag has been bothering me for ages, I didn't care if it stayed or went, but the fact that the limbo is over is a huge relief

Comment: @Nick What if next time it happens to a tag you happen to like? Please do not make this about any tag in particular. This is not what the question is about.

Comment: I don't really know what you're attempting to establish here, but point-by-point: (1) Guilt by association doesn't make sense when applied to tags. There are lots of Meta discussions spanning many years about how [product-vba] tags don't make sense, and should instead be tagged separately [product] and [vba].  If you had an opinion about this, you had many years to make that opinion known. The time for discussion has come and gone. As Nick said, this has been in limbo for *years*, and it's past time someone took the time to do something about it. (2) It's there; I checked before I made the...

Comment: ...comment. But, yes, not *all* of the questions where the tag was removed had been previously edited to add the tag. (3) It now sounds like you're trying to tie me to sweeping, absolute statements. Both moderators and community members work together to improve this site. You were previously arguing that *only* moderators should do this. I said no; community members handle *most* of the retagging. Now you're complaining that a moderator is doing it. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish anymore, other than complain.

Comment: @Nick Everything is a welcome exception until it happens to inconvenience you, isn't it. Please, again, do not turn this into an argument about any specific tag.

Comment: If you don't want to focus on a specific tag, then this a duplicate of [the FAQ on tag burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) and [the FAQ on the tag burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: @CodyGray (3) I was just quoting you [ad litteram](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398413/tag-vigilantism-vs-common-courtesy#comment775980_398413): "*This site is moderated by the community. Regular community members ("random users") handle the retagging, not diamond moderators.*".

Comment: @CodyGray AFAICT the case described here broke almost every rule in [Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/5538420).

Comment: @Nick That link is about a different tag.

Comment: huh, i was on the bountied tab this whole time xd that explains a lot, i'mma just back out and grab coffee (although looks like that tag is getting removed too... maybe that'll get nuked soon too)

Comment: *...the case described here...* You've said you don't want this to be about a specific tag. If this is about the general case, then we have a FAQ for burnination requests. If this is about a specific case, then the tag being discussed matters.

Comment: @BSMP CodyGray's link says among other things "*If a tag has more than 1000 questions, the review work you and the community have to complete is enormous. You would need to fulfill the additional criterion: Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?*". This tag had obviously more than that many posts, and I don't know that even its foes argued that it caused '*a fairly large amount of harm*".

Comment: Ahhhh, this must be about [tag:outlook-vba]... in which case, [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) is still absolutely relevant, because the post really holds for _all_ *-vba tags, as it's the same situation for all of them (and as such my previous statement about being glad the limbo is over still applies)

Comment: Last time you complained about this, it was about edits performed by a non-diamond community member. Now it's the same thing, but done by a user with a diamond. This looks like a duplicate of that [previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398413/tag-vigilantism-vs-common-courtesy), IMO.

Comment: @Nick So you are of the "*guilty by association*" opinion, too. I happen to disagree, but this is off topic here.

Comment: @yivi There is no "*complaint*" in the question as posted. The notion that there is one was a red herring thrown in an early comment, which hijacked the course away from the actual question. I am still hoping for an answer proper, rather than dismissive innuendo.

Comment: There is a complaint, and it's blatantly false to affirm there is none. I can read, thanks. I was not distracted by any comment. The question says there "there was no discussion or dueness", and asks about "safeguards to prevent this from happening". That's the complaint right there on the first few lines, and informs the rest of of the question which maintains the same tone; which you keep using on the comments here.

Comment: @yivi Not sure why you read those as "*complaints*". Both parts you quoted are integral part of the questions. Those would be very different questions without those parts. If you mean that your answer would be 1) Yes, and 2) No, and No, then please by all means post that as answer.

Comment: It's a complaint in the form of a loaded question. It's not possible to answer directly without addressing the assumptions of the questions. And the assumptions of the question were addressed elsewhere (as pointed earlier), which makes answering this question less interesting. I'm out of here. Good luck!

Comment: @yivi All assumptions for *this* question are spelled out *here*, so please leave the other question out of this. Sorry you'd think "*it's not possible to answer*" the question at hand on its own merit.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone reading this and thinking it *isn't* a complaint. Just putting it in the form of a question with an *obvious* implication that what's happened is unreasonable doesn't stop it from being a complaint.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your input, though honestly I don't understand the objection. The question is stated at the top of the post, divided in two parts since the second one is conditional on the first. Would you have still seen it as a "*complaint*" if I had stopped right there and omitted the rest? I thought it was only fair to anyone weighing an answer to give an example for context. Instead, I am being told off for "*complaining*" while the actual question is ignored. If you mean that your answer would be 1) Yes, and 2) No, and No, then please by all means post that as answer.

Comment: You keep saying that answering "yes" is a possible answer, but that disregards the obvious loaded/multiple question nature of your questions. E.g. can't you see that it's impossible to answer the "yes/no" question without **first** dealing with the assumption that it was done _"without discussion and dueness"_?

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, it would clearly be a complaint. You're expressing the opinion that something unfair/inappropriate has happened. Expressing that opinion in the form of a question doesn't stop it from being obvious what your opinion is. If you don't want the "actual question" to be ignored, stop pretending that the "actual question" isn't a complaint. But to my mind, it seems that the answer to the first question is "No" - but that the situation you're describing hasn't actually happened. If you believe it has, then the specific tag *absolutely* matters.

Comment: (And this post would be *much* more straightforward if you'd just come out and said "I believe the way that the outlook-vba tag has been handled is inappropriate. This is what's happened... etc - rather than trying to make it a general case that still happens to show a specific graph...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Suppose I proposed that the `visual-lightswitch` tag be retired and replaced by `visual-studio` `+` `lightswitch` and the proposal gained some support, though it was never carried out. I don't think that would allow me (or anyone) to extrapolate that it's OK to retire `visual-c#` and replace it with `visual-studio` `+` `c#`, or `visual-c++` with `visual-studio` `+` `c++`. However, that's pretty much what happened to outlook-vba. That said, my question is not about the past outlook-vba, but rather about what the rules of the game are in fact, for the sake of future tag removals.

Comment: If you don't *really* don't care about the example you've given, I'd be happy to write an answer saying "Yes, there should be discussion before wide-scale changes." Would you then accept that answer and move on, *without* raising "well what about `outlook-vba`?" (Note that the scenario you described is *not* what happened with `outlook-vba` as the `excel-vba` discussion *specifically* included other `*-vba` tags.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I would be happy to accept such answer. As for the "*discussion*" I assume you mean [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace). I'll only say that outlook-vba was not mentioned in the main post and very little elsewhere, Shog9 only [wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace#comment603479_370095) "It *can*" when asked about it, and among the upvoted answers there was no clear balance in favor of dropping even excel-vba.

Comment: I don't see this as healthy discussion. What you "ask" here is something like "Is it legal to kill another human being?", expecting the obvious "No, of course not", then pointing fingers and saying "But hey, [name here] killed [other name here], arrest him!1!!!". Not very productive. Instead, you can **explain why the tag is required and shouldn't be removed** and see what other people think.

Comment: Honestly, though, this event is _not good_. In the post regarding the *-vba tags, it was clearly specified that this would be done automatically, which avoids license changes, mass bumping, etc. While the way this has been brought up is dubious, and the company should've acted shortly after bringing up the matter, that doesn't really make this event okay in my opinion.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou Thank you for your input (and wish whoever cast the vote to delete had too left a comment why). Sorry to disappoint about "*pointing fingers*", what you suggest would have been an entirely different question than the one I meant to ask here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is it expected that one (or a minority of) determined user(s) be able to single-handedly purge/delete a tag, without discussion or dueness?

No. There should be discussion before wide-scale changes occur. I believe that is generally accepted.

Given that you don't want to discuss any specific cases, I'm expecting this to be accepted without comment...