# Should the tags 'videoview' and 'android-videoview' be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6509906). The user wants to change the tag [videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoview) into [android-videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-videoview) (even though the first seems to be used more than the latter). I'm not an Android developer but based on their descriptions, it seems like both tags are the same and should be merged / made synonyms of each other.

[videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoview) tag wiki:

> VideoView is a specific API provided by Android SDK
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

[android-videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-videoview) tag wiki:

> An Android View to manage and display a video file
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Yep, they're the same thing.

Comment: By the way, the same user seems to be manually retagging more questions with the same tag (for instance https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6510034). What should I do with these suggested edits?

Comment: I would say that they are positive edits, but are not the best way to go about it.  It would be better to get some people active in the tag together to propose a synonym.  `android-videoview` seems like a better name.  If the people don't have enough rep in that tag, you can strategically retag questions.

Comment: I would vote for merging

Comment: I just came across these tags in a review queue and was going to suggest a synonym. It would be nice if this could be actioned.

Comment: There are more requests similar to this one for android related tags. See my submission here fore instance https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350722/merge-tags-android-sharedpreferences-and-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 1):

Most of the questions in the [videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoview) tag were related to Android. Howevre there [were 37 questions which did not have any Android related characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvideoview%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bxamarin%5D+-%5Bandroid-videoview%5D+-%5Bandroid-animation%5D+is%3Aq+-%22android%22&mixed=0). I went through all of these. Many of them were related to video viewing on websites, which I closed/retagged as required. (11 of them were still related to Android).

I merged the two tags, and added a synonym is this direction  [videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videoview) (x 1,841) -> [android-videoview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-videoview) (x 627)