# Merge tags [android-sharedpreferences] and [sharedpreferences]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both tags refer to the same thing, the question is which one should be used.

[sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) is a lot more popular than [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences). However the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag states that the android prefix is preferred for android related tags.

Looks like both [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) and [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity) has been moved to the android prefix so my suggestion would be to go with [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences) makes more sense, the tag [sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) has 10 times more questions. Therefore I get the following error, while creating the synonym:

[image]

[sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) is unarguably the more famous tag. I went through the first 100 questions and all of them seemed related to Android and the tag is not being misused, so I guess it isn't much harmful if we keep the synonym in the reverse direction:

[sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) (x5578) <- [android-sharedpreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sharedpreferences) (x578)

It's now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).