# Make [android-expansion-files] a synonym for [apk-expansion-files]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[android-expansion-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-expansion-files): 132 questions

> Excerpt: The expansion files are used if your application requires more than 50MB of space, you can use expansion files to store additional APK assets.
>
> Each time you upload an APK using the Google Play Android Developer Console, you have the option to add one or two expansion files to the APK. Each file can be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose.

[apk-expansion-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk-expansion-files): 62 questions

> Excerpt: APK Expansion Files include additional data that is required for an Android App if the file size of the App is bigger than 50 MB. It is downloaded and hosted by the Google Play Store.
>
> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB. If your app exceeds 50MB, Google Play allows you to attach up to two APK expansion files that supplement your APK.
>
> [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), the canonical name for this feature is "APK Expansion Files". Given that `android-expansion-files` is not *dominantly* popular, I believe `apk-expansion-files` should be the master.

Comment: 3 years later, the scores are 186/126, and some questions carry both tags.

Comment: 4 years later, the scores are 198/144, and are synonymized, @Alex

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252394/fixing-the-un-prefixed-android-tags