# Split android [appcompat] out to [android-appcompat]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

All Android-related tags seem to be prefixed by `android-`. Hence, I think all [appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat) questions which refer to the Android support v7 appcompat library should be retagged to a new [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat).

Answer (score 4):

As Deduplicator [mentions in a deleted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283805/4099593), appcompat isn't related to just android.

I did a search for the [questions that are likely to not be about android, `[appcompat] -[android] -"android"  is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bappcompat%5D+-%5Bxamarin%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%22android%22++is%3Aq+&mixed=0), and there were 22 questions returned in that search. Amongst them:

- 5 questions were related to the Windows appcompat that Deduplicator was mentioning. The  correct name is "Application Compatibility platform", so I tagged them with [windows-appcompat-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-appcompat-platform). The name can be changed later if needed.
- 1 question was completely unclear, so I just closed and deleted it.

I then renamed the tag as [android-appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-appcompat) and added [appcompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcompat) as a synonym.