# Is [actionbarsherlock] still needed?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Since everything you need to make an app support older versions is now included inside the support libraries, do we still need [actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock) (and [actionbarsherlock-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock-map))??

Comment: We still take care of the [60 year old stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers).  Grudgingly.

Answer (score 12):

**Yes, it is still needed.**

Technology becoming obsolete does not magically disappear any of the existing installations, or the need to maintain them (and maybe port things there or from there).

It might in time do so (Though don't hold your breath, that would be decidedly unhealthy, we *still* have [cobol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol)), but disappearing the tag would not help in removing content absolutely noone ever wants to look at ever again anyway.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to put a note of it no longer being needed in new applications in the tag wiki, if that is really the case.

Comment: Probably. Though I won't do it, as I'm not conversant in the topic, and thus cannot say what the recommended replacement(s) is/are.

Comment: here is the github from actionbarsherlock: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock ... it is marked as deprecated and it advises to use AppCompat

Comment: @Nickolaus: There's a request for a separate tag for android-appcompat: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283800/split-android-tagappcompat-out-to-tagandroid-appcompat

Comment: yeah I just wanted to give an advice about the proper replacement of actionbarsherlock, maybe the wiki or taginfo of actionbarsherlock should be supplied with a link reference to AppCompat