# Let's recycle [recyclerview]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While answering questions I came across two tags which both refer to the `RecyclerView` UI element in Android. The tags in question are:

- [recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview): 993 Questions
- [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview): 205 Questions

Aside from very few outliers all those question definitely are about the `RecyclerView`. That's why I suggest that we make [recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview) a synonym of [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview). My reasoning is as follows:

---

Android tags usually have the the `android-` prefix, for example: [android-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout), [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent), [android-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragments), [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity), [android-asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask), etc...

In fact the tag wiki of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) says this:

> When adding additional tags to questions, please use the
>   Android-specific tags such as [android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) and [android-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-activity), not [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent) and [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity).

So someone who apparently was not aware of this created [recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview) and that one subsequently became more popular but [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview) would actually be the correct tag for the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Is there something special about this particular view that it merits its own tag? Is there not some sort of [android-view] generic tag that could be used in its place? (I'm not an Android developer, so I really don't know the answer to this.)

Comment: It's a monster class with a ton of complexity, and questions about RecyclerView often won't apply generally to Android Views. Kind of like Activities or Fragments. So I'd say it definitely warrants its own tag.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The `RecyclerView` is not just another simple `View` like a `Button` or `ImageView`. It is a very complex topic and definitely warrants its own tag.

Comment: I don't have enough ranking to vote on this but if you have 2.5k points you can vote here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-recyclerview/synonyms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a synonym [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview) -> [recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview) now.
But in my opinion, the synonym should be [recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recyclerview) -> [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview) (vice versa), according to `[android-*]` naming scheme and to prevent future confusion. This was suggested by OP.

Comment: Done now, including [android-recyclerview] being the main tag.