# Merge [alertdialog] and [android-alertdialog]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I would suggest to merge [alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertdialog) and [android-alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-alertdialog) as they clearly refer to the same thing.

Description of [alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertdialog):

> Android AlertDialogs are pop-up dialogs that appear in front of the current Activity.

It states clearly that it is about the Android class `AlertDialog`. It has 1,783 questions in it, and they appear to be about that.

Description of [android-alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-alertdialog):

> A subclass of Dialog that can display one, two or three buttons. If you only want to display a String in this dialog box, use the setMessage() method.

So I have no doubt the two tags are about the same thing. This tag has 1,553 questions that seem to be similar to the questions of the other tag. There even seems to be 191 questions tagged with both.

I have not posted a merge candidate before, so feel free to edit if something is not as it should be. But I really think these two tags are confusing to have both of and therefore should be merged. It would seem [android-alertdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-alertdialog)
 follows the naming convention best.

Comment: Note that before we could merge those tags, we would need to clean up first. A [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alertdialog+-android) for [tag:alertdialog] questions that are not applicable to [tag:android-alertdialog] returns 162 questions (mostly about message boxes, some still android)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth many of these are about Javascript's [tag:alert]

Comment: Updated [query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=%5balertdialog%5d%20-%5bandroid%5d%20-%22android%22%20-%5bflutter%5d%20-%5bxamarin%5d%20-%5bkotlin%5d%20%20is%3aq&mixed=0) with 141 results as of today. If these can be retagged appropriately, I can go ahead with the tag merge. Let me know if you're interested @Vadim

Comment: @BhargavRao Done. I've retagged most of the questions with [tag:alert] or [tag:modal-dialog]. Btw, tag [tag:javascript-alert] is a synonym for [tag:javascript], but I'm not sure it is good.

Comment: @VadimKotov, thanks. The [javascript-alert] was proposed and approved by community, so I don't want to break it.

Comment: @BhargavRao The description is still different on the tags page, even though I can see the synonym was added - https://imgur.com/a/MtJVEli. Also, on a question page there is still an old description. Why is that so?

Comment: @VadimKotov Adding a tag as a synonym does nothing else apart from remapping new questions posted with the source tag to use the target tag. Everything else remains the same. Only once they are merged, the tag wikis are overwritten. I usually wait for a few days to merge, based on the size of the tag.