# Tag synonyms: [android-avd] and [avd]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[android-avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-avd) and [avd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avd) refer to the same thing. - I can't make them synonyms because:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

So it's up to you!

Comment: I assume avd would go into android-avd, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking of.