# Rules for connected tags or tags with prefix

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I just stumbled over the following question:
[Tag synonyms: android-avd and avd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311370/tag-synonyms-android-avd-and-avd?cb=1)

**Question:**

I would be interested in: what should be preferably used in general and are there some rules regarding tag creation and usage?

If there is a risk of confusion, wouldn't it be better to generally use
`android-avd` instead of `avd`?

Comment: If there is just an other word for connected-tags and I searched for the wrong thing, pls just give me a hint.

Comment: There are no rules, questioners that use the tag are in general unaware of existing law books.  Such a question always gets tagged with [android] and nobody ever thinks it makes sense to repeat the word when they tag avd.  Editors that change the tag [create lots of confusion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773/17034).

Comment: Related [Fixing the un-prefixed Android tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252394/1595451)