# Merging of [android-navigation-drawer] and [navigation-drawer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Should we merge [android-navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer) and [navigation-drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer), since they have the same meaning?