# Make [relativelayout] a synonym of [android-relativelayout]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

A couple of years ago I created the [android-relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-relativelayout) tag as a potential synonym to [relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relativelayout). The intention was to make it similar to [android-linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-linearlayout) that was a synonym of [linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linearlayout). Back then I couldn't suggest a synonym since the last appeared way too more than [android-relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-relativelayout).

Some stats:

- [relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relativelayout) - 2583 questions, 2376 of them tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [android-relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-relativelayout) - 1163 questions, 1124 of them tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- The questions tagged [relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relativelayout) that are not tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) are either about CSS (which can be replaced by [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position)) or Xamarin (in which case they can either be removed or replaced by [xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms)).

Now when I see the gap between those keeps decreasing I'm asking if it'd be appropriate to create the synonym?

Comment: This seems similar to [the android textview case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384579/4099593). Relative Layout is not android specific, [and there are many questions that are not related to android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brelativelayout%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bandroid-relativelayout%5D+-%22android%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0). Ideally this can be merged in the reverse direction where [android-relativelayout] is merged to [relativelayout]. (Check the [textview] situation)

Comment: @Bhargav Rao, I noticed some time ago you created a synonym to [tag:android-textview] and wanted to ask on Meta what are the rules behind. Basically what you suggest is to go from specific to general, while I always thought the other way around. Following your point of view, [tag:android-linearlayout] should be mapped to [tag:linearlayout] too. Am I right?

Comment: It totally depends on the tag. For example, in the [one that I did just a few minutes ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387162/4099593), [uiautomator] was an Android only tag so it doesn't matter in what direction we synonymize (we just need to combine both the tags). Relative Layout, Navigation Drawer (ref-https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314896/4099593), Text View, etc are not android specific, and therefore it is better to make them general (like [list], [set], etc). If linear layout is Android specific (looks like it is?!), then [android-linearlayout] being the master is fine.

Comment: @BhargavRao if you exclude Xamarin.Android questions, there will be around 100 questions left, not related to Android

Comment: @VadimKotov, those need to be retagged as well. I will try to write an answer detailing what all we need to do (can't promise a timeline for now, as real life has been a bit hectic these days)