# The [relative] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I've just discovered the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag. Its own excerpt describes *clearly* its meaning:

> Something having, or standing in, some relation to something else.

Its [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/relative/info) is all about *CSS Relative positioning* instead.

The tag has 1,041 questions covering a wide range of topics:

- python relative imports
- css relative positioning
- relative date formatting
- relative path and urls
- ... and more *relative* questions

Burnination criteria list:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It only partially describes the contents of the questions, due to its ambiguity, and its meaning depends *completely* on the other tags used in the question. It doesn't do anything in most cases because [the title already provides the information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative?sort=frequent&pageSize=30).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   It may be on topic, but by itself it doesn't narrow down the specific meaning enough.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No, because its meaning is *relative* to the context.

Comment: Looks like a relatively good tag to burn

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +37/-1. A1 (Saying Yes) +7/0.

Comment: Is [relative] still relevant?

Comment: Please, burninate this terrible tag.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +96/-2. A1 (Saying Yes) +42/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Comment: Now that there are no open questions (as of one month ago), what's the time frame for the closed questions (and tag) actually going away? A couple of new questions popped up in the last week; retagged and sent them on their way, but it seems likely to keep happening

Comment: @PaulRoub Bhargav was taking care of this burnination, but he hasn't been around in the past month. We need a mod to check the questions and finish it up, but currently there is a shortage of mods.

Answer (score 44):

I agree; this tag should be burninated. For CSS, at least, not only is there [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative), but there's also [absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/absolute), [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed), and the minimally-less problematic [sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sticky), all of which are covered by [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position).

So, my suggestion for replacements:

- CSS questions - replace [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative), [absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/absolute), [sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sticky) (where appropriate (e.g. they're using `position: sticky`)), [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) with [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position), as well as replacing [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) with [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position) anywhere you find the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag in concert with [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position).
- Relative path questions (including Python relative imports) - replace [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) and probably [relative-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-url) (100 questions) with [relative-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-path).
- Relative date formatting - there's a [relative-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-date) tag but it has little usage and no wiki/excerpt information... not sure how to proceed there, or if it's even worth having that tag.
- All others (based on the first 6 pages of questions) - just remove the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag.

Comment: Android has RelativeLayout class - see [tag:relativelayout], [tag:android-relativelayout], we should use them.

Comment: @VadimKotov should they be synonyms of each other?

Comment: @Luuklag I think so, there is a request for that, see discussion here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359792/synonym-of-relativelayout

Comment: The other common usage is xamarin, but in many cases this tag overtakes more important tags like xamarin.forms

Answer (score 10):

[relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- CSS questions - replace [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative), [absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/absolute), [sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sticky) (where appropriate (e.g. they're using `position: sticky`)), [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) with [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position), as well as replacing [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) with [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position) anywhere you find the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag in concert with [position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position).
- Relative path questions (including Python relative imports) - replace [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) and probably [relative-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-url) (100 questions) with [relative-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-path). If the question is about Python packages, use [python-packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-packaging)
- Relative date formatting - use the [relative-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-date) tag.
- Related to `RelativeLayout` class in Android - use the [android-relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-relativelayout) tag.

Taken from the other answer, please add more retag guidance as you come across more questions that require retagging.

## Progress:

The [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=relative),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brelative%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brelative%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brelative%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brelative%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198859)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=381970)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: What should be the proper tag for questions about relative position/location? [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867982/calculate-the-relative-position-of-another-nearby-android-phone)

Comment: Looks like [tag:geolocation] would be a good one

Comment: Does the suggestion about [Relative-URL] to [Relative-Path] mean that this is effectively a double-burn?

Comment: We generally cleanup the other bad tags on a question, while handling a burn @Dan.

Comment: Agree we should we be using [tag:layout] for questions about positioning of GUI controls WRT other controls when [tag:css] and [tag:android-relativelayout] do not apply?  [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/layout/info): *The layout tag is for questions about the placement, alignment and justification of objects with respect to a containing element. For questions pertaining to CSS, use the 'css' tag instead.*

Comment: Or actually the [tag:position] tag also seems to cover this scenario.  [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/position/info): *Position refers to the location of an element relative to its container, typically on the horizontal and vertical axes.*  Layout: 23,586 questions.  Position: 7,811 questions.

Comment: @BhargavRao No open questions left!