# Merge request for 2 tags: [textview] and [android-textview]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

According to their description they should be merged IMHO. Can it be done? Is there any reason why it's not merged yet?

[textview](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/textview/info):

> **Android** widget that displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it. A TextView is a complete text editor, however
>   the basic class is configured to not allow editing

[**android**-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-textview/info):

> Displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it.

Comment: `textview` is the more popular tag, but my gut feeling is, that `android-textview` would be more clear to distinguish.

Comment: What is the point of [android-textview]? It is already going to be combined with an [android] tag, so this is just unnecessary verbiage. @nfec

Comment: @CodyGray, well, the reason I opened this discussion is exactly because I asked a question and had 6 tags, so I had to remove one. In this sense it sounds like android-textview = android + textview, so I would be able to remove android. On the other hand then nobody who watches android would notice my question. This is a very interesting question, but IMHO it deserves a separate discussion, concerning all android-X vs android + X tags (and actually I guess it's even Y-X vs Y + X :) Maybe we should have meta-tags: meta-android = andorid + android-*

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your request. It was a reply to the first comment on the question, suggesting that [android-textview] would be somehow preferable to just [textview]. Indeed, we only need a single [textview] tag. And no, removing [android] would be silly if it is indeed a question about programming the Android platform.

Comment: @CodyGray, I understood and agree. I just added, that if android-X will be kept, and X merged into it, then it would make it possible to tag a question with android-X, and not to tag it with android (and the only legit reason I can see is if 5 tags are not enough, but if it's possible then people will do it anyway) but then I would be interested in having a meta-android or umbrella-android "tag", and watching it would automatically give all android related tags (android, android-*, but also textview or similar, clearly android related tags) Of course this would be a totally new functionality.

Comment: How does this tag-synonym work? Is there any outcome from this request? Is there a point in opening similar requests for other tags, or it's a waste of time?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

[textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textview) is a generic tag for text views of any kind. Android textview makes up a majority of it, but it isn't the only place where textview is available.

When we see the list of posts in that tag [where there is no mention of android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btextview%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%22android%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0), we can easily see that the tag is being used for the same concept, that is for text view widgets, but not using Android.

Therefore, saying that [textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textview) and [android-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-textview) are the same is wrong. Similarly, if the tag description is wrong, then the tag description must be edited in to be generic.

Ideally the tag [android-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-textview) isn't necessary at all. It is like saying [python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-list) instead of adding [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)+[list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list). The best way out here would be to:

- Add [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) to the list of 93 questions in [android-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-textview) [that don't have the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-textview%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0).
- Merge [android-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-textview) into [textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textview)
- Edit the tag description of [textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textview) into something useful.

Comment: Why is this marked as completed? There is a synonym [tag:android-textview] -> [tag:textview], these tags were not merged.

Comment: The tags were merged long back, @Vadim.