# Can we make [cardview] a synonym of [android-cardview]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Currently the below two tags are used for  [**`Android CardView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView).

- [android-cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cardview)

  > CardView is a widget used to show complex lists and cards in your app, and it has material design style by default.
- [cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardview)

  > CardView is a widget for implementing 'card-styled' views in Android.

As per my opinion we need to merge these two tags, because these two tags are used for questions related to **Android CardView**.

Questions tagged [android-cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cardview) 1,800 questions

Questions tagged [cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardview) 377 questions

Comment: Or can we make [cardview] a synonym of [android-cardview]

Comment: looks similar to this request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318170/merge-request-for-2-tags-textview-and-android-textview

Comment: For anyone downvoting this request, please share your opinion in comments or as an answer. I see no reason to decline this request.

Answer (score 2):

**Cardview is a layout** and everyone knows that. When cardview is [searched on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cardview&oq=card&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2j0l2.1053j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), the first thing is an **Android reference**. Why should we have two tags for the questions falling under the same category? 
I know that tags should tell about the question and are **not meant to group questions** but then why to have two different tags for the same topic? Also, questions are getting diverted, where the [android-cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cardview) should have had 2177 (now 2176) questions.
 
 I believe it will be easier for everyone to search for questions related to cardview **if it is not grouped into two different tags** with the same meaning. 
There's no other use for the [android-cardview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-cardview) other than in Android itself.