# Merge [broadcastreceiver] and [android-broadcastreceiver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I noticed these two tags:

[broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) :

[image]

and: [android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver) :

[image]

I think (personal opinion) these two should be merged together as [android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver).

I know broadcastreceiver has **way** more questions and followers.

It'll only change the name right? It won't mess up the questions or followers?
If it does, than [broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcastreceiver) is the one to go with.

But I think [android-broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-broadcastreceiver) is a bit more specific.

Comment: I agree! We already have android-specific tags for other android components, like android-service, android-intent, android-activity, android-service. As the "broadcastreceiver" tag is only used for Android, there should be no questions tagged with "broadcastreceiver" that are not Android-specific.

Comment: Can I update your question and include [synonym-request]? I think it makes sense, since all [tag:broadcastreceiver] questions are related to Android

Comment: Not a great excerpt on either of those; it's basically copy-pasta from http://www.alignminds.com/blog/broadcast-announcements-android/...

Comment: Was synonymized through community vote.