# Make [connectivitymanager] a synonym of [android-connectivitymanager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both tags have no wiki, but they are related to the same [Android SDK class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html).

Some stats:

- [connectivitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connectivitymanager) - 25 questions, all tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [android-connectivitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-connectivitymanager) - 13 questions, all tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

I think this synonym would be helpful:

[connectivitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connectivitymanager) -> [android-connectivitymanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-connectivitymanager)

It will use the current `[android-*]` naming scheme.