# Make [vectordrawable] a synonym of [android-vectordrawable]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both tags are [Android-specific only](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html) and should be merged.

Some stats:

- [vectordrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vectordrawable) - 97 questions, no wiki, all tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [android-vectordrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-vectordrawable) - 298 questions, all tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

I think this synonym would be helpful; it is currently suggested:

[vectordrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vectordrawable) -> [android-vectordrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-vectordrawable)

It will use the current `[android-*]` naming scheme.

As an alternative, we could just retag all questions to [android-vectordrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-vectordrawable).