# Merge tags [fragmentmanager] and [android-fragmentmanager]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are two tags that reference the same thing [android-fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragmentmanager) and [fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragmentmanager).

[fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragmentmanager) has 303 questions.

[android-fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragmentmanager) has 208 questions.

I propose to merge them, and maybe keep the [android-fragmentmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragmentmanager) since it clearly defines the technology it belongs to.

Comment: Suggesting it as a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-fragmentmanager/synonyms) would probably do it. But there are only 11 users that could do that.. So a mod may help out?

Comment: @Cody Gray, it seems that there is a new tag with 7 question that could be added as a synonym also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragment-manager. Should I create a new question for it or is this comment enough?