# Merge [espresso] and [android-espresso]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The two tags, [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) and [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso), are for the exact same subject and have the same tag wikis. One of them should be merged with the other.

There are 261 questions about the Android Espresso Testing Framework that use both tags.
Besides that, 549 out of 563 questions use the [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) tag in combination with the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.
The other 14 questions use the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or the [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso) tag. So all the questions fit in the [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso) tag.

I personally think that [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) should be merged in [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso) 
 since all subjects that belong to Android have the `android-` prefix. Besides that [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso) has more followers and questions.

Comment: *"I personally think that espresso should be merged in android-espresso"* - Me too, double espressos are the best.

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252394/fixing-the-un-prefixed-android-tags