# Can we merge both these tags, [constraint-layout] and [android-constraintlayout]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both the tags [constraint-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constraint-layout) and [android-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-constraintlayout) are used for [**`ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

- [constraint-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constraint-layout)

Constraint layout is a type of layout that uses `anchors` and `edges` of views to mark their positions relative to each other.

- [android-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-constraintlayout)

A new type of layout is available in the Android support repository built on top of a flexible constraint system, marking views positions relative to each other.

I propose merging the tags [constraint-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constraint-layout) and [android-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-constraintlayout), because *both* the tags are used for questions related to `ConstraintLayout`.

Questions tagged [constraint-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constraint-layout):    153 questions

Questions tagged [android-constraintlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-constraintlayout):    1,271 questions

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you have a `[constraint-layout]` related question that's not about Android?

Comment: Constraint Layout could refer to something in Xilinx Vivado software

Comment: Or how about the constraint based layout for [Gtk](https://github.com/ebassi/emeus)?

Comment: @theGtknerd for that we can create new tag like [Gtk-constraint-layout] beacuse when see question of [constraint-layout] tag all question is about `android ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252394/fixing-the-un-prefixed-android-tags