# Can we make [framelayout] = [android-framelayout]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both the tags [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout) and [android-framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-framelayout) are used for [**`FrameLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout)

- [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout)

FrameLayout is a simple Android layout designed to hold only one child.

- [android-framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-framelayout)

It is an Android layout that uses the screen to display views that can be stacked on top of each other, with the most recent child added on top.

I propose merging the tags [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout) and [android-framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-framelayout), because both the tags are used for questions related to FrameLayout.

Questions tagged [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout): 786 questions (782 of them (more than 99%) are also tagged with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))

Questions tagged [android-framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-framelayout): 182 questions

Comment: Keep the second description though. FrameLayouts can hold more than one child.

Comment: Appear to also be some C# questions about FrameLayoutPanel with this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141844/getting-object-of-usercontrol-from-a-list-of-usercontrols-in-framelayoutpanel . The name's close enough that it might be excusable.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, in that case, the correct tag should be `[FrameLayoutPanel]` not `[FrameLayout]`

Comment: I don't particularly care one way or another, just pointing out that there *are* already non-android questions using the tag. I only looked on the first page tho so there are likely others.

Comment: There are current 4 question that are tagged c#, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout+c%23  so those would have to be retagged before that happens

Comment: Looks like the other 3 seem to also be tagged with Xamarin.Android, which implies that they're talking about the android [framelayout] itself.

Comment: I suggest to create a synonym [tag:framelayout] -> [tag:android-framelayout], so it can follow naming scheme for Android tags - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252394/fixing-the-un-prefixed-android-tags

Comment: Interesting edit @Vadim, I had stored this meta, and all the 24 of the ones that didn't have the tag in a fresh new Chrome window to work on tonight.. ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao Sorry, I can't figure out what you're talking about. I just added [tag:android] to 20+ questions that did not have this tag, but are about Android

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was pointing at. Thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were totally 21 questions in the [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout) tag, which didn't have [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag. Vadim updated 19 of them, which leaves us with 2. One of them was related to the Android framelayout. The other one ([How to add more frame layout to Typo3 backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212309/how-to-add-more-frame-layout-to-typo3-backend)) was related to layouts in frames, from which I removed the tag.

As [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout) had more than 6 times the number of questions as [android-framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-framelayout), it was not possible to add as a synonym. However, given the fact that it was very clear that both of them were referring to the same concept, I merged the tags, and added [framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framelayout) as a synonym.